# How to select 2 rows from JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I use this Java code to get `name` from a `JTable` with selecting a row.

`String name=table.getModel().getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow() , 0).toString();`

I want to know how to do the same but with selecting two rows from  `table` at the same time and get the values for the variables`String name` and `String name1`.
**UPDATE:** `solution`

````
table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
 int[] rows = table.getSelectedRows();
String name1=table.getModel().getValueAt(rows[1] , 0).toString();   
String name2=table.getModel().getValueAt(rows[0] , 0).toString();```
````

Comment: There are multiple parts to what is described above. First look at [`ListSelectionModel.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html#setSelectionMode(int))

Comment: BTW - don't [edit] using the 'back button'. Use the link below the post, which will take into account edits made by others.

Comment: *"i am a begginer"* Then it's a great time to learn. **Try implementing it.** Other things to learn: 1) SO is not a code generation machine. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data for the table. 3) If trying it and posting an MRE / SSCCE of your effort is too hard for you as a beginner, do easier projects for now. Anything involving a GUI is not a good task for a newbie.

Comment: @Shym, *when i select the second row the firs row selection  disappears* - how do you select multiple items in any application??? Think about the File Explorer in Windows. If you simply click on a file the previous file selection is lost and the current file is selected. If you want both to be selected you press the Control button while you click on the file. A JTable works the same way.

Comment: Did you use the JTable.getSelectionModel() method to change the selection mode?

Comment: @camickr what i need it s something like the pricture in the link without using chekbox  [link](https://imgur.com/wxEgvLv) .

Comment: And what is the problem??? The tutorial contains the complete demo code showing how to accomplish that. The first comment by Andrew also shows you how to allow for multiple selection. Don't know how we can offer any more help since you have been given all the information needed to solve the problem and you haven't posted an [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `table.getSelectedRows();` to get multiple selected rows.

```
int[] rows = table.getSelectedRows();
String name = table.getModel().getValueAt(rows[0], 0).toString();
String name1 = table.getModel().getValueAt(rows[1], 0).toString();
```

To limit the amount of rows you can select you should make a custom `mouselistener` that selects and deselect rows.

```
table.setEnabled(false);
table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        Point p = e.getPoint();
        int row = table.rowAtPoint(p);
            
        ListSelectionModel i = table.getSelectionModel();
            
        // Toggle clicked row and check if there is only two rows selected
        if (i.isSelectedIndex(row)) i.removeSelectionInterval(row, row);
        else if (table.getSelectedRows().length < 2) i.addSelectionInterval(row, row);
    }
});
```

Comment: it doesn't work when i select the second row the firs row selection s disappear

Comment: You need to hold and drag, or press ctrl while clicking the other row.

Comment: I have added code for limiting and toggle selections to the answer

Comment: `table.addMouseListener(..` Use a [`ListSelectionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionListener.html)! See the tutorial (and code) for same for the reasons why it is better.

Answer (score -1):

For me use checkbox instead to select multiple rows. Or make a selection mode option like dropdownbox and then get the data of a selected rows like ID and then store it in array. Use those id that you stored in array and query it.